# Using HQL in place of criteria in the below method

Tags: hibernate, hql, criteria

I have the below method named `findExcludedFlagForfvAndij` and in that I have used criteria , please advise how can i change the criteria  so that i can use  hql in place of criteria , please advise what will be the hql for this

```
 public abfsm findExcludedFlagForfvAndij(IOAfv fv,ijType ij , String sx){       
            abfsm ioafvAndij=null;

        if (fv!=null && ij!=null){

        //****** want to use HQL instead of criteria******
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(abfsm.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("fvISOCode", fv.getSdmfvId()));

        criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("sourceSystem" ), 
                  Restrictions.eq("sourceSystem", sx)));

        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ijCode", ij.getCode()));
        criteria.setFirstResult(0);
        criteria.setMaxResults(1);
        ioafvAndij = (abfsm) criteria.list();
        }       

        return ioafvAndij;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Criteria code :

```
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(abfsm.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("fvISOCode", fv.getSdmfvId()));

    criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("sourceSystem" ), 
              Restrictions.eq("sourceSystem", sx)));

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("ijCode", ij.getCode()));
```

You can use below HQL code:

```
String hql="from abfsm where fvISOCode = :fvISOCode and ijCode = :ijCode and (sourceSystem IS NULL or sourceSystem = :sourceSystem)";     

Query query= session.createQuery(hql)
    .setParameter("fvISOCode", fv.getSdmfvId())
    .setParameter("ijCode", ij.getCode())
    .setParameter("sourceSystem", sx);
```